# Oracle SQL: in 'WITH' statement, how to avoid empty result row in conditional aggregate function select from different table

Tags: sql, oracle, union-all

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Persons_A (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_A
    (PersonID,LastName,FirstName)
    values(11,'LN_A1','FN_A1');

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_A
    (PersonID,LastName,FirstName)
    values(12,'LN_A2','FN_A2');

CREATE TABLE Test_Persons_B (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_B
    (PersonID,LastName,FirstName)
    values(21,'LN_B1','FN_B1');

INSERT INTO Test_Persons_B
    (PersonID,LastName,FirstName)
    values(22,'LN_B2','FN_B2');

commit;
```

I want to conditionally use aggregation function on only one of the tables with IF and UNION ALL within WITH clause (based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330601/2041023). but is there an easier way to do this, without having to add another SELECT wrapping around this one like the following?

```
---------- use IF and UNION ALL, aggregation function COUNT, but return two rows ----------
var TEST_TBL varchar2(20);
exec :TEST_TBL := 'test_persons_a';

with Test_count_id as (
      select COUNT(PersonID) as CNT_PID
      from Test_Persons_A
      where UPPER(:TEST_TBL) = 'TEST_PERSONS_A'
      union all
      select COUNT(PersonID) as CNT_PID
      from Test_Persons_B
      where UPPER(:TEST_TBL) = 'TEST_PERSONS_B'
     )

select * from Test_count_id
```

result:

```
   CNT_PID
----------
         2
         0
```

The inconvenience is even more obvious here:

```
---------- use IF and UNION ALL, aggregation function MAX, but return two rows, one of which is empty ----------
var TEST_TBL varchar2(20);
exec :TEST_TBL := 'test_persons_a';

with Test_max_id as (
      select MAX(PersonID) as Max_PID
      from Test_Persons_A
      where upper(:TEST_TBL) = 'TEST_PERSONS_A' 
      union all
      select MAX(PersonID) as Max_PID
      from Test_Persons_B
      where UPPER(:TEST_TBL) = 'TEST_PERSONS_B'
     )

select * from Test_max_id
```

result:

```
   MAX_PID
----------
        12
           (-- empty row)
```

**So, how I can do this in a clean way?**

EDIT: removed the extra question to avoid confusion

FURTHER EDIT: if I add another SELECT to wrap the SELECT ... UNION ALL ... SELECT, it kind of works, but like I said, I am hoping to avoid this ugliness:

```
---------- use IF and UNION ALL, and a wrapper, aggregation function MAX, but return one row ----------
var TEST_TBL varchar2(20);
exec :TEST_TBL := 'test_persons_a';

with Test_max_id1 as (
        select Max_PID from ( 
              select MAX(PersonID) as Max_PID
              from Test_Persons_A
              where UPPER(:TEST_TBL) = 'TEST_PERSONS_A' 
              union all
              select MAX(PersonID) as Max_PID
              from Test_Persons_B
              where UPPER(:TEST_TBL) = 'TEST_PERSONS_B'
        ) where Max_PID is NOT NULL
     )

select * from Test_max_id1
```

result:

```
   MAX_PID
----------
        12
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Adapt this example as needed. The logic is to add an extra column to the `UNION ALL`, to keep track of the source table of each row; and use that in your condition.

```
with
  test_count_id as (
    select person_id, last_name, first_name, 'TEST_PERSONS_A' as source_table
      from test_persons_a
    union all
    select person_id, last_name, first_name, 'TEST_PERSONS_B'
      from test_persons_b
  )
select count(person_id)
from   test_count_id
where  upper(:test_tbl) = source_table
;
```

Comment: thanks, it's a sound idea. But I think the full union all will have significant impact on performance, hence will perhaps not be acceptable to my specific case.

Comment: @Stochastika - I suggest you give it a try. The Oracle optimizer will push the predicate (the `WHERE` condition) to each member of the `UNION ALL`. It will not touch the base table for which the predicate becomes false. If you are not familiar with the concepts, just test it and you will see.

Comment: @Stochastika - Another way to code the same idea is to have the `WHERE` clause in each branch of `UNION ALL` (and to do away with the extra column). `with test_count_id as ( select person_id from test_person_a where upper(:test_tbl) = 'TEST_PERSONS_A' union all ... ) select count(persion_id) from test_count_id`. The Optimizer will transform the query in my solution into this second version (in this Comment). You can write it directly this way if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this right, your problem is, that your current queries return two rows. You only want one row.

You could do the `UNION ALL` first, also selecting a literal indicating the table the row comes from. Then filter on that indicator in the aggregation query.

```
WITH TEST_COUNT_ID
AS
(
SELECT COUNT(PERSONID) CNT_PID
       FROM (SELECT PERSONID,
                    'TEST_PERSONS_A' TBL
                    FROM TEST_PERSONS_A
             UNION ALL
             SELECT PERSONID,
                    'TEST_PERSONS_B' TBL
                    FROM TEST_PERSONS_B) X
       WHERE TBL = UPPER(:TEST_TBL)
)
SELECT *
       FROM TEST_COUNT_ID;
```

Another option would be cross joining both aggregating queries. Use a `CASE` to only output the value of the target table.

```
WITH TEST_COUNT_ID
AS
(
SELECT CASE UPPER(:TEST_TBL)
         WHEN 'TEST_PERSONS_A' THEN
           A.CNT_PID
         WHEN 'TEST_PERSONS_B' THEN
           B.CNT_PID
       END CNT_PID
       FROM (SELECT COUNT(PERSONID) CNT_PID
                    FROM TEST_PERSONS_A) A
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(PERSONID) CNT_PID
                        FROM TEST_PERSONS_B) B
)
SELECT *
       FROM TEST_COUNT_ID;
```

Or you could use use a `CASE` to create an ordering value putting the row from the target table first. Use `ROWNUM` to select only the first row.

```
WITH TEST_COUNT_ID
AS
(
SELECT CNT_PID
       FROM (SELECT CNT_PID
                    FROM (SELECT COUNT(PERSONID) CNT_PID,
                          CASE UPPER(:TEST_TBL)
                            WHEN 'TEST_PERSONS_A' THEN
                             0
                           ELSE
                             1
                         END O
                         FROM TEST_PERSONS_A
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT COUNT(PERSONID) CNT_PID,
                         CASE UPPER(:TEST_TBL)
                           WHEN 'TEST_PERSONS_B' THEN
                             0
                           ELSE
                             1
                         END O
                         FROM TEST_PERSONS_B) X
                  ORDER BY O) Y
       WHERE ROWNUM = 1
)
SELECT *
       FROM TEST_COUNT_ID;
```

From a performance perspective however you'd be best off to build the respective query in your application only selecting from the actual target table.

Comment: Seriously? You came up with the first solution on your own, 40 minutes after it was posted already? (It seems you didn't quite understand it though - why do you need the outermost `SELECT`?)

Comment: @mathguy: Yes I did. Sometimes the notification, that an answer was added, doesn't work and I had it open for a while. So I didn't even see your answer before I posted mine. No need to get angry, I don't need to copy from you. But I kept my answer as it significantly adds something, I assume. And I wrote it that way, so that all stuff happens within the CTE and only a `SELECT * FROM CTE` is needed, as I assumed that's how the OP wants it. Your right though, if that requirement is dropped, some levels of `SELECT` could be spared. I never claimed anything else.